How to call function starting with percent?
I have defined the following Bash function:
%a%() { echo hello; }

I can confirm the function is really defined:
$ declare -f %a%
%a% () 
{ 
    echo hello
}

How do I call it? Because when I do, then:
$ %a%
-bash: fg: %a%: no such job
$ set +m
$ %a%
-bash: fg: no job control


It's surprising it lets you define this, because I don't think it can be called. Variable and function names have to be valid identifiers.

The problem is only when % is the first character, since % at the beginning of a word is reserved for job control. Even if JC is not enabled, it's still parsed.

This should probably be reported as a bash bug that it doesn't catch it when defining the function.

Wow, neat find. Doesn't work via any kind of quoting, escaping, expansion, command, alias, function, or anything else I can think of.

great find, same issue in zsh
zsh
ZSH_VERSION=5.8
~  %a%() {
~ function> echo wtf
~ function> }
@Z800 ~ %a%
fg: job not found: a%

I'm using zsh and everything works like a charm calling a subshell. doing this: echo $(exec %a%)

This is definitely not a valid POSIX name, so I'm firmly in the "it's a bug that this can be defined at all" camp, particularly with the special meaning % has in exported function declarations.

When the shell is in POSIX mode (see Bash POSIX Mode), fname must be a valid shell name and may not be the same as one of the special builtins (see Special Builtins). In default mode, a function name can be any unquoted shell word that does not contain ‘$’. (from manual)

%() { :; } can be defined as a function with only % as fname

This is a bug in Bash. It finds the function here, but then forgets about it here. This patch fixes the bug in the devel branch.

this runs but discards side-effects as it is a subshell context: ('%a%' & wait)

afunc="%a%" ; ${afunc} worked for me.

@l'L'l are you using bash? Which version? If so,post an answer.

Try to be more specific in your question, like:
1: What is the purpose of declaring/executing the function named with %a%? I ask because it may be possible to use other practices, perhaps even better ones to perform what you want with this type of bash function declaration.
2: Which terminal will be run (bash/zsh/etc...)?
2.1: If possible, what version of the terminal will you run?

This is to facilitate the response of people like me who respond hoping to help and have negative reviews due to lack of specificity and some "redundancies", etc. Some members can be quite critical about what is answered, so it is important to be critical and specific when asking as well.
After all, I bet that practically everyone here just wants to help you and everyone who uses this forum.

hi @RafaelMori What is the purpose of declaring/executing the function named with %a%? Fun. The original purpose was to do some templating for python click bash autocompletion, but it is simpler to use _. Which terminal will be run (bash/zsh/etc...)? Terminal (the interface used to view text) is irrelevant. The shell is bash. I do not mention any other shells in the question and treat zsh as "fun fact". everyone who uses this forum I came to the conclusion this forum is literal and specific. I ask specifically about bash and a specific question how to do something.

Some members can be quite critical It's great. I many times answered vague questions wrongly just to be downvoted. It happens. It is sometimes beneficial to wait for OPs to give more hints what he wants in comments then to rush with an answer.

At least with bash 5.2 (I don't have any other easy test systems), you can escape the % with \ and then end the call with &
from man bash

If a command is followed by a & and job control is not active, the default standard input for the command is the empty file /dev/null.  Otherwise, the invoked command inherits the file descriptors of the calling shell as modified by redirections.

user@host:~$ %a%() { echo hello; }
user@host:~$ \%a\%&
[1] 12345
hello

Note this works with and without job control set +m

See also jhnc comment. You can also '%a%' &. As for (I don't have any other easy test systems), use docker, you can docker run -ti --rm bash:5.1 test almost any version.

In bash (tested GNU bash 5.2.21) the function can be duplicated with a simple process substitution and then called:
$ source <(declare -f %a% | sed 's/^\%a\%/afunc/')
$ afunc

In zsh (5.9) it's much easier:
$ afunc="%a%" ; ${afunc}

If you don't want two identical functions laying around then unset after calling it.
$ unset -f afunc


That's not really calling the existing function, though. It's defining a new function using the same body, but a different name.

@chepner: True, but it's a workaround at the very least.

This answer is not correct. It completely changes the question by assigning a function without the % symbols. Does not answer what was asked as asked.

@RafaelMori, How did I change the question? That's nonsense. You should explain what the "correct" answer is since you seem to know, although it's not really for you to decide anyway.

This doesn't answer the question.

@lesderid, Invalid comment.

@l'L'l No. The question asks how to call a function that has a specific name, not how to call a copy of it that has a different name.

@lesderid, Yes, That is how it's done in this circumstance.

@l'L'l It still doesn't answer the question though. Your post describes a workaround that might be functionally equivalent, but you fail to clarify the fact that it is a workaround and not a direct answer to the question.

@lesderid. Read my second comment; I clearly state it's a workaround.
